# Display full url for default route in Asp Mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I would like to display the full URL when someone navigates to the root of my website. If they navigate to www.mysite.com, the default routing properly handles it and displays the correct page.  The issue is that the URL in browser displays www.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com/unity/hygiene (which is set up as the default route).

I've tried add a begin request in the global.asax

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var originalPath = ctx.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
    if (originalPath == "/") 
        ctx.RewritePath("/unity/hygiene/");
}
```

It does rewrite the path, but that does not update the URL.

I have URL Rewrite installed in IIS (IIS 7.5, Server 2008R2), but I haven't been successful with that either.  I tried a rewriteMap:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="HygieneDefault">
            <add key="http://www.example.com:8002/" value="http://www.example.com:8002/unity/hygiene/" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
    <globalRules>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

How do I display the full URL in the browser for the default route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to check in the controller for the current URL and redirect if it was the root.

```
var url = Request.RawUrl;
if (url == @"/")
{
    Response.Redirect("/Unity/Hygiene");
}
return View();
```