# how to show the controller and action in browser tab c# mvc while route config is default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In C# MVC, how can I get the default controller and action to be shown on browser. In my route config default controller/action is AddPerson/Index. But while running the program it is not showing AddPerson/Index on the browser.

My RouteConfig.cs is:

```
namespace AddPerson
{
  public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AddPerson", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

My Browser link : `http://localhost:53076/`

I want : `http://localhost:53076/AddPerson/Index`

Content coming is same, only address is not coming .

How to solve this?

Comment: the reason is they are default. If you want them to show always change default controller to Home and default action to Index. And then call rediectToAction from their and redirect to AddPerson and Index.

Comment: Some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812851/display-full-url-for-default-route-in-asp-mvc-website) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131929/asp-net-routing-display-complete-url)

Comment: It will interpret the rout to the default one which you set to controller => AddPerson and action => Index, that means if the rout has not been set, it will redirect to this address i.e. controller and action