# ASP.Net Core default route as /Home with it shown by default

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I use the mapRoutes in ASP.Net Core I can set the default controller route. When starting the application the entry point will be the default Home but all that will be shown is https://localhost:43594 rather than showing the /Home on the end.

Is there a way to explicitly enforce this?

Comment: what do your routes look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several workarounds:

- Workaround 1: you can remove the defaults as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301573/how-to-force-mvc-to-route-to-home-index-instead-of-root)
- Workaround 2: create a different default action and redirect to /Home/Index from there as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131929/asp-net-routing-display-complete-url)
- Workaround 3: check for current URL and redirect if it is root as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812851/display-full-url-for-default-route-in-asp-mvc-website)

Answer (score 3):

For changing Route URL, you could try `URL Rewriting Middleware` or `Custom Middleware`.

Here are available options in `Startup`:

- Rewrite URL

  ```
   app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("/","/Home",true));
  ```
- Redirect URL

  ```
   app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("/", "/Home"));
  ```
- Custom Middleware

  ```
      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
      {
          if (context.Request.Path == "/")
          {
              context.Response.Redirect("Home/", true);

              return;
          }
          await next();
      });
  ```

  Use the above options before `app.UseMvc`

  ```
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
  ```

Comment: I will test this soon and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: `AddRedirect("/", "/Home")` does nothing. Maybe the regex is incorrect?